# Is there a theory of GADT beyond Haskell?

Tags: types, theory, gadt

ADT can be easily explained, via Model Theory, as a model of an algebraic theory. But GADT puzzles me, is it still a model of an algebraic theory, or is it a model of a geometric theory, or is there a proper type-theoretical description of what is GADT from the type theory p.o.v.?

Comment: Look at [Semantics of Advanced Data Types - Patricia Johann](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YhUE32PxGWk), especially [video 2/4](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w3n8NXaADdg)